# Add SlideToggle Effect Drop Down Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this jQuery dropdown menu. I am having trouble trying to get it to have a slide down toggle effect (like this: http://jsfiddle.net/LaSsr/188/). If anyone can apply this type of slide effect to the below JSfiddle that would be very much appreciated. Thank you :)

**JSFIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/6mWZa/182/

```js
(function($, undefined) {
  var open = [];

  var opts = {
    selector: '.dropdown',
    toggle: 'dropdown-toggle',
    open: 'dropdown-open',
    nest: true
  };





  $(document).on('click.dropdown touchstart.dropdown', function(e) {
    // Close the last open dropdown if click is from outside the target dropdown
    if (open.length && (!opts.nest || !open[open.length - 1].find(e.target).length)) {
      open.pop().removeClass(opts.open);
    }

    var $this = $(e.target);

    // If target is a dropdown then toggle it...
    if ($this.hasClass(opts.toggle)) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $this = $this.closest(opts.selector);

      if (!$this.hasClass(opts.open)) {
        open.push($this.addClass(opts.open));
      } else {
        open.pop().removeClass(opts.open);
      }
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="language" class="dropdown">
  <a href="#language" class="dropdown-toggle">English</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="dropdownCool">
      Hello1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="locale" class="dropdown">
  <a href="#locale" class="dropdown-toggle">
        
        London</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="dropdownCool">
      Hello2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: JQuery has `.slideDown()` and `.slideUp()`: http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you have any idea how to implement this in the code? I don't know how to :/

Comment: The docs show examples of implementation - also this may be useful: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_slideup.asp

Comment: I have no experience coding and have been trying to get this to work for hours. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not  able to solve it yet  please check if this is useful

```
/* dropdown */
.dropdown-menu {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    display
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
   height:0px;
   transition:  height 0.15s ease-out;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Add this in your `.dropdown-menu` class and

```
.dropdown-open > .dropdown-menu {

          height: 400px;
        transition:  height 0.25s ease-in;
    }
```

I had remove the display none from the style and added height 0 and overflow hidden

please check your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6mWZa/186/